# Relationships in same table

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, relationships

I'm trying to make 2 "one to many" relationships on the same table, as I have employees managed by TLs supervised by SPVs.

Employees table consists of (**ID** -PK- , name , hire_date ,,,,,)  it's the same data for TL and SPV also

on the ERD I've made it as a one to many on the same table but I've no idea how to make it on SQL (I can't detect what should be refer to who)

I've thought about giving up the one to many relationship idea and add a "type" as 1 if employee and 2 if TL and 3 if SPV but i need to know every TL's employees for example (TL#1 have the employees John , Paul, Smith ,... in his team) and so on

**Note: I'm not sure if it's the right thing to make it as a one to many relationship , if there's any other way I'd really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql? just put the same table in the REFERENCES clause.

if you can't do it, do it in a separate SQL sentence.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    spv INTEGER UNSIGNED NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY ( spv ) REFERENCES employee (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Whenever I try to make ID as a reference for TL or SPV it gives me error 1452 : cannot add or update a child raw

I'll check this error and tell you if it worked .... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you are trying to do that with a new table or an existent one?

Comment: I'm doing that with an existing table, I'm using mySQL query browser so i just add the column and say that this will be fk

Comment: check the values in the existing field you want to make a reference from. if the values have not a corresponding entry, the sentence will fail

Comment: try a SELECT referenced_field FROM employees WHERE referenced_field NOT IN (select ID from employees).

Comment: you should not get any value in the previous comment. if you do, the ALTER TABLE will not work, because you would get an integrity error

Comment: I've doubled check the values and data types (though they r both int), I've tried the select statement you told me and it give me null

Comment: in employees I have only 2 records with ID 123 & 456 and I've assigned  TL to 123 & 123 ..... If i'm not mistaken then this way TL have a reference in ID which is 123

Comment: right now it worked for me: ALTER TABLE  `employee` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `spv` ) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ;